# Cómo poder arrastrar varios elementos a una misma caja

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero poder arrastrar los elementos que yo quiera y todos puedan ser metidos en la misma caja, en este ejemplo depende de una id el elemento para poder ser aceptado en la caja y además solo se puede uno, quiero quitar eso y pueda meter cualquier objeto o por lo menos los que tengan la misma clase.

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
#caja {
  width: 250px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="caja" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>

<h1 id="mover" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">TEXTO</h1>
```

el resto de elementos que quieren estar también en la caja

```
<h2></h2>
<p></p>
<!-- etc... -->
```

Comment: [Aquí](https://devcode.la/tutoriales/draganddrop-html5/) en la parte del final puedes ver un ejercicio con imágenes de pokemón, espero te ayude es muy práctico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede hacerlo así, obteniendo la class de los elementos, espero te funcione, aunque te recomiendo que cada elemento lleve su id, para fines de buenas prácticas.

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("dragged-id", ev.target.className);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("dragged-id");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementsByClassName(data)[0]);
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementsByClassName(data)[1]);
}
```

```css
#caja {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="caja" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>

<h1 class="drag" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">TEXTO</h1>

<p class="drag" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">parrafo</p>
```